# parsing vimeo json response

Tags: ios, json, vimeo

In my iOS app i want to display the videos of a particular account in Vimeo, i have completed the OAuth steps. I used videos.getAll method and it give the response in json format, it gives the details of video. I have retrieved the video id's. I want to use collection view to display the videos. Is there a way to get the thumbnails for those videos,to display them in collection view.Thank you

Comment: i know that the question is off the topic from the title parsing viemo json response, but i edited it so that no need to post another question for this problem.

Comment: we can use the vimeo api to get detials about thumbnail but, doing that step for every video is time taking. if the user has around 100 videos then we cant use that process for 100 times it would take a lot of time. is there a way to get the thumbnails dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it we just have to use the video.getThumbnailUrls method from vimeo advanced api..