# Parsing Vimeo Json response in ios

Tags: ios, json, vimeo

I got this json response

```
{
   "generated_in" = "0.0283";
    stat = ok;
videos =     {
    "on_this_page" = 3;
    page = 1;
    perpage = 50;
    total = 3;
    video =         (
                    {
            "embed_privacy" = anywhere;
            id = 73198189;
            "is_hd" = 1;
            "is_watchlater" = 0;
            license = 0;
            "modified_date" = "2013-08-27 01:29:16";
            owner = 20303618;
            privacy = anybody;
            title = Untitled;
            "upload_date" = "2013-08-27 00:57:36";
        },
                    {
            "embed_privacy" = anywhere;
            id = 73197989;
            "is_hd" = 0;
            "is_watchlater" = 0;
            license = 0;
            "modified_date" = "2013-08-27 01:24:17";
            owner = 20303618;
            privacy = anybody;
            title = sample2;
            "upload_date" = "2013-08-27 00:52:40";
        },
                    {
            "embed_privacy" = anywhere;
            id = 72961770;
            "is_hd" = 0;
            "is_watchlater" = 0;
            license = 0;
            "modified_date" = "2013-08-23 05:57:48";
            owner = 20303618;
            privacy = anybody;
            title = sample;
            "upload_date" = "2013-08-23 05:25:44";
        }
    );
};
}
```

when i am trying to parse it for the video id. 
The technique i used is 
i converted that json into NSDictionary jsondata and

```
NSString *videoid = [[[jsondata      objectForKey:@"videos"]valueForKey:@"video"]valueForKey:@"id"];
NSLog(@"video string is %@",videoid);
```

the result is:
(
    73198189,
    73197989,
    72961770
)

but i am not able to access the normal string functions on that string to retrieve the id's.
it is saying an error unrecognized selector was sent.
Is there a better way to parse that string, i tried google but every post says the same approach.

Comment: Edit your previous question rather than posting duplicate ones. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18461640/parsing-vimeo-json-response

Comment: @Amar yes both are similar, but in this question i specifically asked for help in parsing json response for resolving the error, but in previous question i asked for the approach for displaying videos. Both can be asked in same question, but i thought that it would be confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You not getting a string but an array of strings, the JSON response holds mutiple videos. The code you used will retrieve all the `id` of all the videos.

You can loop thru the found videos like:

```
NSArray *videoIdArray = [jsondata valueForKeyPath:@"videos.video.id"];

for(NSString *videoId in videoIdArray) {
   NSLog(@"video string is %@",videoId);
}
```

Comment: Thank you.. got is. the json response only gives the details about the videos. is there a way to get some thumbnail for the video.